# Jasmine Add To Promise

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, angular-promise

I'm running into this issue:

```
Expected 2 to equal 'Promise::6492 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}1'.
```

My code looks like this:

Spec:

```
this.allRows = element.all(by.name('row'));
```

Jasmine

```
var prevRowCount = this.allRows().count()

this.addRow();

expect(this.allRows.count()).toEqual(prevRowCount+1);
```

How can I add one to the count that this.allRows.count() returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor's [ElementFinder](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) and [ElementArrayFinder](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) are built around Selenium's [WebElement](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#behind-the-scenes-elementfinders-versus-webelements), thus they [rely on promises heavily](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#behind-the-scenes-elementfinders-versus-webelements).

Protractor [provides an adapter for Jasmine](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/tree/jasminewd2), so the latter can embrace its promise nature and unwrap the promises transparently in `expect` and matchers.

So the spec should stick to unwrapping the promises by hand. Or the promises can be matched directly. It becomes a trivial task with ES5:

```
expect(this.allRows.count()).toEqual(prevRowCount.then(function (count) {
  return ++count;
}));
```

And it is more convenient with ES6 syntactic sugar:

```
expect(this.allRows.count()).toEqual(prevRowCount.then((count) => ++count));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to *explicitly resolve* the `prevRowCount` promise:

```
prevRowCount.then(function (prevRowCount) {
    this.addRow();

    expect(this.allRows.count()).toEqual(prevRowCount+1);
});
```

Note that you don't need to do the same for the newly obtained row count inside the `this.allRows.count()` since `expect()` would resolve it implicitly before checking the expectation.